# DataTable shows data received from SignalR only on first page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable, pagination

I have cell in my dataTable where im putting some data from SignalR and it look like this

```
<td class='cameras middleal'><?php echo $cam; ?> </td>
```

And i'm putting here div's

```
$cma = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LPR_RuleToCameraIdx] where [RuleId] = '".$q['Id']."'");
    while($cm = sqlsrv_fetch_array($cma)) {
        $cam = $cam." <div id='cameras".$q['Id']."".$cm['TrackerId']."'></div> ";
    }
```

And my SignalR is

```
var connRuler = $.hubConnection("https://<?php echo $ruler; ?>");   
var RulerHubProxy = connRuler.createHubProxy('SignalRImporterSvcHub');
connRuler.start().done(function () {
    RulerHubProxy.invoke('getAllCameras').done(function (cameras) {
    <?php 
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LPR_RuleToCameraIdx] ');
    while($q = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?>
        for(var i=0; i< cameras.length; i++) {
            try {
                var srvid  = cameras[i].ServerId;
                for(d = 0;  d < javascript_array.length; d++) {
                    if(javascript_array[d][0] == srvid) {
                        servername = javascript_array[d][1];
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("cameras<?php echo $q['RuleId']; ?>" + cameras[i].CameraId ).innerHTML= "" + servername + " " +cameras[i].CameraName + "";
            } catch(err) {
            }
        }
    <?php  } ?>  
});
});
```

On first page of dataTable there's everything fine and it's showing data
[screen of first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ3Gg.jpg)

But there's problem when i switch to the second, third, etc. page and it's showing nothing [screen of second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc6GO.jpg)

If I switch row number to i.e. 20,50,100  it shows all 20,50,100  first records fine, but on second page still problem is the same.

Does anyone know why it's only working on first page of dataTable ?

Comment: second page? do you mean Another html file?